# AttributeError: 'Conv3d' object has no attribute 'padding_mode'

Tags: pytorch, onnx

Hello to anyone who may sees this. I'm trying convert a c3d model to onnx for general use purpose.

The C3D train code is took from :https://github.com/jfzhang95/pytorch-video-recognition

So the original env for c3d model is **torch=0.4.0** python=3.5.2 as requested README.MD.

```
from network import C3D_model
import torch
import torch.onnx

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print("Device being used:", device)


def test():

    model = C3D_model.C3D(num_classes=2)
    checkpoint = torch.load('C3D-ucf101_epoch-3.pth.tar',
                        map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    torch.save(model, 'c3d_thunder.pkl')
    dummy_input1 = torch.randn(1, 3, 16, 112, 112)
    torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input1, "C3D.onnx", verbose=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

At first I tried to convert this model under original env, but met this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/pytorch-video-recognition/model2onnx.py", line 31, in <module>
    test()
  File "/workspace/pytorch-video-recognition/model2onnx.py", line 27, in test
    torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input1, "C3D.onnx", verbose=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/onnx/__init__.py", line 25, in export
    return utils.export(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 84, in export
    _export(model, args, f, export_params, verbose, training, input_names, output_names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 154, in _export
    _onnx_opset_version, defer_weight_export)
RuntimeError: ONNX export failed: Couldn't export operator aten::max_pool3d
```

After some efforts on searching for solution, I decided to save the whole model to .pkl and reload it under **torch=1.1.0**. It works for loading model, but still has some problems in transformation.

```
import torch
import torch.onnx

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")


def test():
    PATH = 'c3d_thunder.pkl'
    model = torch.load(PATH)
    dummy_input1 = torch.randn(1, 3, 16, 112, 112)
    torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input1, "C3D.onnx", verbose=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

still got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/google/Desktop/onnx_test/t1.py", line 33, in <module>
    test()
  File "C:/Users/google/Desktop/onnx_test/t1.py", line 29, in test
    torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input1, "C3D.onnx", verbose=True)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\__init__.py", line 25, in export
    return utils.export(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\utils.py", line 131, in export
    strip_doc_string=strip_doc_string)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\utils.py", line 363, in _export
    _retain_param_name, do_constant_folding)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\utils.py", line 266, in _model_to_graph
    graph, torch_out = _trace_and_get_graph_from_model(model, args, training)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\utils.py", line 225, in _trace_and_get_graph_from_model
    trace, torch_out = torch.jit.get_trace_graph(model, args, _force_outplace=True)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\__init__.py", line 231, in get_trace_graph
    return LegacyTracedModule(f, _force_outplace, return_inputs)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\__init__.py", line 294, in forward
    out = self.inner(*trace_inputs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 481, in _slow_forward
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\google\Desktop\onnx_test\network\C3D_model.py", line 46, in forward
    x = self.relu(self.conv1(x))
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 481, in _slow_forward
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 468, in forward
    if self.padding_mode == 'circular':
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch_learn\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 539, in __getattr__
    type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Conv3d' object has no attribute 'padding_mode'
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem? Thanks for your time!~

Comment: You should post your code and not multiply images it will be easier to follow .

Comment: Sorry for that, I already updated the code and error content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the latest version of PyTorch?